# JFET Audio switch, does not work in simulation?

Tags: switches, analog, jfet

This is a circuit I've found online and apparently it is taken from the very rare audio book by National semi. The circuit is used to switch a signal on and off at a transition time that the user sets using the RC input. The problem is that I can't seem to get this to work in simulation. Any ideas what I might be missing out of?

[image]

Comment: The info you give is not enough. What's the exhibited problem? Which simulation program are you using? Posting the captured schematics in the simulation program (showing the parameters of all the components and signal sources/loads) would also help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The circuit you posted *can* work. These are the results of a hastily conceived LTSpice simulation with some guesswork values for the components:

[image]

[image]

Therefore there could be something wrong in the simulation parameters or the choice of the values of the components.

As I said in a comment, you should post additional information for us to be able to troubleshoot the problem.

**Note:** this circuit works (i.e. switch opens) under the assumption that the control signal's amplitude is much higher than the amplitude of the controlled signal, here 10V and 100mV respectively. Well, actually the assumption is that the maximum positive value of \$V_{ctrl}\$ must be greater than the maximum positive \$V_{sig}\$ value + \$V_{GS(off)}\$ of the JFET, but since in practice \$V_{GS(off)}\$ is not very predictable it's better to err on the safe side.

This is the easiest mistake I guess you could have done (insufficient amplitude of control signal), but this is wild guessing in absence of more data from you.

Comment: +1 I see a master at work :-)

Comment: That's odd... I had a very similar circuit on Multisim. Rc was 100k, in and out resistors both 100k. Vin was 200mV, control was 5V, 10V and 15V and none worked. Perhaps something was wrong... next time I'll set it up in LTSpice. Thanks!

Comment: @user34920 Another wild guess is that the model of the JFET is not accurate or it has some idiosyncrasies. I don't like multisim very much (I used it only briefly). It has some nice features useful for didactic work (LEDs lighting up and so on), but I definitely prefer LTspice: free, unrestricted use, small footprint, excellent code base (I never ever got a crash or a freeze); the user interface is a bit old style, but once you get the hang of it (and you master some SPICE directives)  you can set up a complex simulation in a breeze.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati I hate to say it but I actually took a class where we had to run simulations using SPICE, all written in text. I got a perfect score in the exam but now, some time after that I'm way too lazy to look at anything that shows the directives. A great example of poor choice making! :)

Comment: @user34920 Mmmh... professor allergic to "modern" GUIs? Meh! Although knowing how to hack a netlist together is useful also in LTspice (when defining subcircuits, for example, or when debugging a simulation that gives strange results) it is overkill for the most common cases! LTspice has an extremely good guide (in standard Windows .CHM format), if you're proficient in English. Your past experience with directives should give a distinct advantage there. Browse the guide and see.

Comment: @LorenzoDonati Not exactly that, they had the course book and it was written back in the days when all you have is SPICE and no one wants to update the book... so there you have it. The surprising part is that after you get used to write the netlist you can actually do it really fast, however after not doing that for a while it becomes slow again :)