# Photoresistor audio switch on battery power

Tags: analog, photoresistor

I'm trying to build a light-driven chime silencer for a wall clock. The schematic from https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/177401/18259 seem like a very good starting design for this:

[image: Schematic from other EE question]

It, however, requires a control voltage of 10V. Testing this in LTspice confirms that 3V won't drive this. I'd like to run this ideally on a single 1.5V battery, or at most two. (This would work on a 9V battery, but it feels like overkill for the problem.)

I'm also uncertain where would be best to add the [photoresistor](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9088) (1k-10k) that won't excessively drain the battery.

The chime signal seems to be about 250mV, and I'd like to squelch it when there is low light on the photoresistor.

(Unfortunately, while I took several electronics classes in college, it's been too many decades to remember how to actually design these things.)

Responding to the helpful comment from @dandavis: I believe just using a photoresistor in series going to make it much quieter when I want it on (the resistance range is 1-10kHz), and then make the sound very proportional to the light. I want it to be off (or extremely quiet) when there's little light and full volume when there is a lot of light, with a fairly sharp transition that I can tune.

Comment: is that a chime signal or a chime drive? a signal would usually be at a higher voltage, but I could see the drive getting pulled down to that. I'm not 100% sure of your setup, but a photo transistor in series with the chime sounds like it would work (low R when light, high R when dark).

Comment: It's not clear what function you're trying to accomplish.  Do you want to mute the clock when the light is ON or something else?

Comment: jwh - the opposite.  No light = no sound.

Comment: right, no light, no sound. The signal is tied directly to a small speaker (8ohms I believe).

Comment: @dandavis updated the question; I believe just putting the photoresistor in series is going to be too crude. I want it nearly silent (ideally fully silent) at 2am when the lights are out and there's no daylight, but full volume during waking hours (under both daylight and artificial light in the room).

Comment: a phototransistor isn't a photoresistor, which at best get down to dozens of ohms and would thus hamper the buzzer too much. You want two phototransistors wired in parallel in opposing polarity to carry an AC signal (only in the light, assuming the buzzer is passive, one will work for an active buzzer). A photodiode (or two) would also work. Think of both as a "sharp" photoresistor with steep cliffs instead of ramps; a threshold more than a linear.

Comment: @dandavis The speaker is passive (in that there's no separate battery for it; it's driven completely off the signal lines from the clock movement). I think I'm picturing how to build this with 2 photodiodes, but I'm unclear how you bias them to control the light requirements. Can you help answer that?

Comment: optically with glue, poster putty, or even masking tape can be used to make the threshold darker. if it's too low already  (it thinks day is still night) then it's more complicated and i might reconsider the idea.

Comment: Thanks; this is very helpful. I haven't designed anything with photodiodes before. Is there a fairly standard model to purchase and experiment with? Is the usual setup in series like a variable resistor, or is the intent more like a zener diode, to short the circuit?